# Scroll Width undefined

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I'm trying to give the user the opportunity to scroll with his mouse by pressing the left mouse click and then dragging the mouse.

and according to the movements the site scrolls.

I want this just for the x-axe

I have a Canvas bigger than the Window Screen

I came up with this code

```
var mouseDown = false;

    var previousPos = $(window).scrollLeft();
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", setDown);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", setUp);
    function setDown() {
        mouseDown = true;
    }
    function setUp() {
        mouseDown = false;
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMove);
    function handleMove(event) {
        if(mouseDown) {
            console.log(`Previous: ${previousPos}`);
            console.log(`Current: ${event.movementX}`);
            console.log(`Calc:  ${previousPos+event.movementX}`);




                let oldPrevious = previousPos;


                previousPos = previousPos+event.movementX;
                window.scroll(previousPos, 0);

               console.log(window.scrollWidth);

                switch (checkScrollbar()) {
                    case "right":
                        previousPos = oldPrevious;
                        window.scroll(previousPos, 0);
                        break;

                    case "left":
                        previousPos = oldPrevious;
                        window.scroll(0, 0);
                        break;
                }
        }   
    }

    function checkScrollbar() {
        if (window.scrollWidth - $(window).scrollLeft() == $(window).width())
        {
            return "right";
        }
        else if($(window).scrollLeft() == 0)
        {
            return "left";
        }
        return "safe";
    }
```

Notice that window.scrollWidth is undefined!

$(window).scrollLeft() gives the exact pixels every time but i need the maximum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check is unnecessery**

the jquery scrollLeft Method already fixes that problem.

So the code is just:

```
var mouseDown = false;
var previousPos = $(window).scrollLeft();
document.addEventListener("mousedown", setDown);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", setUp);
function setDown() {
    mouseDown = true;
}
function setUp() {
    mouseDown = false;
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMove);
function handleMove(event) {
    if(mouseDown) {
        $(window).scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft()+event.movementX);

    }   
}
```